# How to pass value from <option><select> to form action

Tags: html, forms, submit, action, form-submit

I need to pass a value in option select to action where I have agent_id=

Can anyone help?

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php?action=contact_agent&agent_id=">
<select>
<option value="1">Agent Homer</option>
<option value="2">Agent Lenny</option>
<option value="3">Agent Carl</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yuck. Any reason you can't just use a post instead of a get?

Comment: Is it possible to do it just only via HTML?

Comment: @JohnFx - I presume the `yuck` is for `mixing both POST and GET in the same query` which, while strange, is allowed by the HTML specification.  See the answer by @Marko for an example of the server expecting this behavior.

Comment: If you're trying to get the text value ("Agent Homer") instead of the option value ("1"), use `myForm.selectedOptions[0].text`.

Answer (score 62):

You don't have to use jQuery or Javascript.

Use the `name` tag of the select and let the form do it's job.

```
<select name="agent_id" id="agent_id">
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code example of this? I'm not able to fully understand your proposal. Thanks.

Comment: this seems to be a good answer but there is very little information. Perhaps there should be some context

Comment: Link to course https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp and demo 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_value

Answer (score 21):

Like @Shoaib answered, you dont need any jQuery or Javascript. You can to this simply with pure html!

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php?action=contact_agent">
  <select name="agent_id" required>
    <option value="1">Agent Homer</option>
    <option value="2">Agent Lenny</option>
    <option value="3">Agent Carl</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

1. **Remove** `&agent_id=` from form action since you don't need it there.
2. **Add** `name="agent_id"` to the select
3. **Optionally** add word `required` do indicate that this selection is required.

Since you are using PHP, then by posting the form to `index.php` you can catch `agent_id` with `$_POST`

```php
/** Since you reference action on `form action` then value of $_GET['action'] will be contact_agent */
$action = $_GET['action'];

/** Value of $_POST['agent_id'] will be selected option value */
$agent_id = $_POST['agent_id'];
```

As conclusion for such a simple task you should not use any javascript or jQuery. To @FelipeAlvarez that answers your comment

Comment: Best answer ! Thank you for such a detailed explanation on simple stuff that we sometimes don't exactly know the behavior.

Answer (score 8):

you can simply use your own code but add name for the select tag

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php?action=contact_agent&agent_id=">
    <select name="agent_id">
        <option value="1">Agent Homer</option>
        <option value="2">Agent Lenny</option>
        <option value="3">Agent Carl</option>
    </select>
```

then you can access it like this

```
String agent=request.getparameter("agent_id");
```

Answer (score 6):

with jQuery :
html :

```
<form method="POST" name="myform" action="index.php?action=contact_agent&agent_id="  onsubmit="SetData()">
  <select name="agent" id="agent">
    <option value="1">Agent Homer</option>
    <option value="2">Agent Lenny</option>
    <option value="3">Agent Carl</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

jQuery :

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   $(this).attr('action',$(this).attr('action')+$('#agent').val());
   $(this).submit();
});
```

javascript :

```
function SetData(){
   var select = document.getElementById('agent');
   var agent_id = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
   document.myform.action = "index.php?action=contact_agent&agent_id="+agent_id ; # or .getAttribute('action')
   myform.submit();
}
```

Comment: I suspect the select name should be `agent_id` in which case the action should just be `index.php?action=contact_agent`

Comment: There's no need to include jQuery to do such a simple thing ... :(

Comment: @HeXa Yup, call the SetData function when you want to submit the form. +1'd

Comment: So complex ! Imagine it when you have dozen of selects in your form....

Answer (score 6):

instead of trying to catch both POST and GET responses - you can have everything you want in the POST.

Your code:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php?action=contact_agent&agent_id=">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Agent Homer</option>
    <option value="2">Agent Lenny</option>
    <option value="3">Agent Carl</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

can easily become:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact_agent">
  <select name="agent_id">
    <option value="1">Agent Homer</option>
    <option value="2">Agent Lenny</option>
    <option value="3">Agent Carl</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit POST Data</button>
</form>
```

then in index.php - these values will be populated

```
$_POST['action'] // "contact_agent"
$_POST['agent_id'] // 1, 2 or 3 based on selection in form...
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a POST when the agent is selected, and there's no submit button.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @AlanBaljeu - yes to fully submit the form you would either need a button or optionally a js action to submit the form upon the change event of the select - the answer as provided was focused on sending  all form fields via POST vs a mixed GET/POST form submission.