# How to use form select value to action method (without query)

Tags: html, node.js, forms, pug

I'm using pug to render some pages for my nodeJS server. In this case I'm trying to use the value captured in the form select in order to change the action method.

So, the idea is use the group name selected to go to that page:

```
form.w3-container(action="http://localhost:5004/groups/" + (option selected down below) method="GET")
   select.form-control(data-toggle='select' class="form-control" data-placeholder='Disabled results')
      option group1
      option group2
      option group3
   button.btn.btn-success(type='submit') Go
```

Any suggestion on how can I do this, if possible without jquery (if it is not possible without I, an explanation on how to "use" it would be very much appreciated).

From what Shoaib said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149088/how-to-pass-value-from-optionselect-to-form-action), it should be possible, but I dint't quit understand his suggestion, poor context :/

Answer (score 2):

HTML code:

```
<form id="myForm" class="w3-container" action="" method="POST">
  <select id="mySelector" data-toggle='select' class="form-control" data-placeholder='Disabled results'>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="group1">group1</option>
    <option value="group2">group2</option>
    <option value="group3">group3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

ECMAscript code:

```
var selector = document.getElementById("mySelector");

selector.addEventListener("change", function() {
  changeAction();
});

function changeAction() {
  var finalAction = document.getElementById("myForm").action = "http://localhost:5004/groups/" + selector.value;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ytvhqrs0/1/

Comment: I binded an "Event Listener" to the select tag. When the select's value changes, the Event Listener calls a function that's update the form's action.

Comment: But will that trigger when the submit from the form is executed? Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but my question is: is that js to add to my javascript function files / or somewhere in the html page and if when the submit is executed the get request is executed @Gutem

Comment: You should add that in the same page that your HTML is.
As you are using `pug`, use the `script.` pug-style, and add the js code in the next line...